Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs rec: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None)dtype=float32>]
`I am upgrading tensorflow 2.4.1 with 2.15.0. I am re-using the model trained with 2.4.1. I am unable to do batch-wise prediction int he upgraded version. The input format is taken as 1 tensor.
Model input shape: [(None, 46, 1), (None, 46, 1)]
Batch data shapes: [(200, 46, 1), (200, 46, 1)]
Model summary is identical in both versions.
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class predictDataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, inData, nsamps, batch_size=250, dim=46,
                 n_channels=1, inData_ch2=None, n_classes=2,
                 avg_num=3, befN=18, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.inData = inData
        self.inData_ch2 = inData_ch2
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.avg_num = avg_num
        self.befN = befN
        self.part_start = (self.befN + 1) * self.avg_num + self.avg_num // 2 - (self.befN + 1)
        self.part_window = self.dim + 1
        self.obj_window = (self.dim + 1) * self.avg_num
        self.part_tile = np.tile(np.arange(self.dim), (self.batch_size, 1))
        self.part_tile += np.arange(self.batch_size).reshape(self.batch_size, 1)
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.nsamps = nsamps
        self.on_epoch_end()
        self.batch_count = self.__len__()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.ceil(self.nsamps / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        batch_data = self.inData[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size + self.obj_window - 1]
        num_points = batch_data.size - (self.obj_window - 1)
        X_OBJ = np.empty((num_points, self.dim, self.n_channels))
        X_PART = np.empty((num_points, self.dim, self.n_channels))
        for i in range(self.n_channels):
            X_obj, X_part = self.__data_generation(batch_data, num_points)
            X_PART[:, :, i] = X_part
            X_OBJ[:, :, i] = X_obj
        return (X_OBJ, X_PART)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        # Optional: Implement shuffling if needed
        if self.shuffle:
            self.indexes = np.arange(self.nsamps)
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def get_part_data(self, batch_data, num_points):
        'Prepare part data'
        part_end = self.part_start + num_points + self.part_window
        temp_data = batch_data[self.part_start:part_end]  # Required samples
        temp_data = np.diff(temp_data)  # temp_data[1:] - temp_data[:-1]
        X_part2 = temp_data[self.part_tile[:num_points, :]]
        return X_part2

    def get_obj_data(self, batch_data, num_points):
        'Prepare object data'
        X_OBJ2 = np.empty((num_points, self.dim))
        for i in range(self.avg_num):
            temp_end = batch_data.size - (batch_data.size - i) % self.avg_num
            temp_data = batch_data[i:temp_end]
            temp_data = temp_data.reshape(-1, self.avg_num)
            temp_data = np.sum(temp_data, axis=1) / self.avg_num
            temp_data = np.diff(temp_data)
            num_windows = temp_data.size - self.dim + 1
            obj_tile = np.tile(np.arange(self.dim), (num_windows, 1))
            obj_tile += np.arange(num_windows).reshape(num_windows, 1)
            X_OBJ2[i::self.avg_num] = temp_data[obj_tile]
        return X_OBJ2

    def __data_generation(self, batch_data, num_points):
        'Generates data for one batch'
        X_part = self.get_part_data(batch_data, num_points)
        X_obj = self.get_obj_data(batch_data, num_points)
        X_part = X_part - np.mean(X_part, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
        X_part = X_part / ((np.std(X_part, axis=1)).reshape(-1, 1) + 1e-100)
        X_obj = X_obj - np.mean(X_obj, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
        X_obj = X_obj / ((np.std(X_obj, axis=1)).reshape(-1, 1) + 1e-100)
        return X_obj, X_part

X_test = np.arange(1140)
pred_length = X_test.size-l_start-l_end
bsize = 200 

testgen = predictDataGenerator(X_test.reshape(-1),
                    pred_length,batch_size=bsize,dim = Window,
                    avg_num = avgN,
                    befN = window1,shuffle=False)
print(len(testgen))
probs = bd_model.predict(testgen)

ERROR:
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None) dtype=float32>]`
